# How to tie a button element to an object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm developing a browser cash register app that lets you add items and an attached price to a cash register div. From there, you can (theoretically) click the "add item" button to log the item and then display the total price.

I've accomplished this by using JavaScript to take text information and create elements with various classes. Each item div contains an "add item" button, but I'm not sure how to make the button log the item the button is contained it. I've used an array to create a group of objects and I've converted the price field to an object property.

```js
function addNewItem() {
    var inputFieldValue = document.getElementById("nameInputField").value;
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(inputFieldValue);
    var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var createP = document.createElement("p");
    var createImg = document.createElement("img");
    var createButton = document.createElement("button");
    var containerDiv = document.getElementById("itemContainer");
    var addItemText = document.createTextNode("Add Item");
    var priceValue = document.getElementById("priceInputField").value;
    var objs = [];
    i++;
    objs[i] = new Object();
    objs[i].price = priceValue;
    createDiv.className = "groceryItem";
    createDiv.id = "groceryItem";
    createP.className = "itemName";
    createP.id = "itemName";
    createImg.className = "itemImage";
    createImg.id = "itemImage";
    createImg.src = inputFieldValue + ".jpg";
    createButton.className = "addItem";
    createButton.id = inputFieldValue;
    createP.appendChild(textNode);
    createDiv.appendChild(createP);
    createDiv.appendChild(createImg);
    createButton.appendChild(addItemText);
    createDiv.appendChild(createButton);
    containerDiv.appendChild(createDiv);  

}
```

[A picture of the app in its current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWBs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pushing the object to your array?
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/push

Comment: Every time an item is added, it gets added to the array. My problem is that I don't know how to pull the price value of the object using the buttons. Each added item has a button element attached, and I need those buttons to return the object price value when clicked.

Comment: I don't know if I got you but add a hidden element (using css) with like display: none for example and change the display to make it visible when the button is clicked?